# How to resolve a http baddata Angular error?

Tags: angularjs, rest, jakarta-ee

I am working on an application using Angular in the frontend and J2EE in the backend , I made a form where i have to post data to be saved in the database
  The problem that the post work fine but I cant get the server response after the add ,always i get this error(strangely the error comes in gray color not in red and usually)

[image: error screenshot]

> Error: [$http:baddata]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$http/baddata?p0=%7B%22success%22%7D&p1=%7B%7D
>       at angular.min.js:6
>       at nc (angular.min.js:96)
>       at angular.min.js:97
>       at q (angular.min.js:7)
>       at xd (angular.min.js:97)
>       at f (angular.min.js:99)
>       at angular.min.js:134
>       at m.$digest (angular.min.js:145)
>       at m.$apply (angular.min.js:149)
>       at l (angular.min.js:102)

Here's the angular code

```
$scope.wflow = {
    "worcode": "HELLOoo",
    "wordest": "AVDOSS",
    "worstatus": "ACTIF",
    "worheight": 0,
    "lancode": "EN",
    "worlabel": "Salut monde",
    "wordescription": "Salut monde",
    "size": 0
};
$scope.submitForm = function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.wflow));

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: host + 'api/workflow/add',
        data: $scope.wflow
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

};
```

And here's the Java one

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<String> addWorkflow(@RequestBody LWflow lworkflow){
  service.addWorkflow(lworkflow);
  return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"success\"}", HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

this is the html part if needed

```
        <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Code</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="worcode" class="form-control" ng-model="wflow.worcode"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Destination</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="wordest" class="form-control" ng-model="wflow.wordest"><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Status</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="worstatus" class="form-control" ng-model="wflow.worstatus"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Height</b></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="worheight" class="form-control" ng-model="wflow.worheight"><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Langue</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lancode" class="form-control" ng-model="wflow.lancode"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Label</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="worlabel" class="form-control" ng-model="wflow.worlabel"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Description</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="wordescription" class="form-control" ng-model="wflow.wordescription"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Taille</b></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="size" class="form-control" ng-model="wflow.size"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
      </form>
```

note that the error comes from the errorCallback function

Comment: The response string `ResponseEntity<String>("{\"success\"}",` is not valid JSON. Fix it.

Comment: @georgeawg can u tell me how ?

Comment: What is your intention? What do you want the user to receive?

Comment: @georgeawg i want just return a json contain anything

Comment: How about `ResponseEntity<String>("{\"result\":\"success\"}",`

Comment: THAT'S IT !!! you saved me sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a server side problem because the response was not valid to read by angular
PS: read @georgeawg's last comment

Answer (score 3):

This error can be caused because response is in json string so angular trying to parse that json string to JSON.
i used transformResponse and error resolved.

```
$http({
    url : url,
    method : 'POST',
    data: data,
    transformResponse: [
        function (data) { 
            return data; 
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved using a object class that encapusulates the error message and in the angular response i catch the right property.

Example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public default ResponseEntity<S> save(@RequestBody T entidade,HttpServletRequest request){
    try {
        getService().save(entidade.build());
        return new ResponseEntity(entidade, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (EasyQuoteServiceException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new Message(e.getMessage(),MessageType.ERROR), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

I have a class called Message

```
public class Message implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 904580124116256409L;

    private String message;
    private MessageType typeMessage;



    public Message() {
        super();
    }
    public Message(String message, MessageType typeMessage) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.typeMessage = typeMessage;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public MessageType getTypeMessage() {
        return typeMessage;
    }
    public void setTypeMessage(MessageType typeMessage) {
        this.typeMessage = typeMessage;
    }

}
```

and in the angularjs response method

```
        }).catch(function(error){
            $scope.erromessage=error.data.message;

         });
    }else{
        mensagem+="As senhas não parecem ser iguais;";
    }
    if(mensagem!=""){
        $scope.erromessage = mensagem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case you should return your response like this example:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json" )
@ResponseBody
public String saveCustomer(@RequestPart(name = "customer") Customer customer, @RequestPart(name = "file") MultipartFile file) { return "{\"message\": \"success\"}"; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This way

```
 $http({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: host + 'api/workflow/add',
        data: angular.toJson($scope.wflow)
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide plunker for this. So we can sort out issues