# why http service in angularjs always error

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I have some code below:
app.js

```
app.controller("carCtrl", function($scope, $http, $window) {
  $scope.createTenCar = function() {
    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/EX11_29112018_spring_restful/cars"
    }).then(function success(response) {
      alert('ok');

    }, function error(response, headers, config) {
      alert("fail");
      console.log(response);
    });
  };
```

file html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#!car">show all car</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-controller="carCtrl" ng-click = 
       "createTenCar()">create ten car</a></li>
 </ul>
```

function create car in java, it create a random car. It alway return message success and status 201 when I test on postman:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cars", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createTenCar() {
        String message = carSerVice.createTenCar();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(message, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

But when I run file html $http.post always jump to error function. Can some one help me.[this is my screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PEQd.png)

[image]

Comment: In js code your function name is `createTenCar`, in html `createTenInsurance`. Are you sure that `createTenCar` is called?

Comment: sorry. I have a mistake, I edited it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945234/how-to-resolve-a-http-baddata-angular-error 
Try sending the response in JSON from backend.

Comment: I think responseentity auto parse an object to JSON. If first param is an object it will be parse in JSON. But I am not sure

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $http:baddata
Bad JSON Data](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$http/baddata).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. 
method carSerVice.createTenCar() return a message like this "success".
it is incorrect format to parse in JSON, I replace "success" by "\"success\"" and it work

Comment: I'd recommend precising where you made that modification, and show what the updated code looked like before in the question, and after in the answer. It may help the people who will be having a similar problem in the future and find this Q&A when looking for help. Also with that kind of problem (client having issues with data sent from the server), it helps a lot to know what the problematic data exchanged actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when bad data comes from your backend. Recommend you to check whether response in the backend is valid